# SSJS in Xpage Extension Library Calendar

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

It seems a problem from long time and I am not able to find an alternative to this. I have an extension library calendar on my xpage and "onNewEntry" event I would like to create an entry in the existing document, however, the problem is that it only supports CSJS (Client Side Javascript) and ignores all SSJS (or runs them on page load). Can anyone please suggest an alternative to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that because the Extension Library calendar control is basically just a wrapper around the iNotes calendar (which is traditional Domino web and not XPages), it just accepts CSJS.

There are (at least!) a couple of options.

1) The best practice approach would be to use a JSON RPC call. This allows you to run SSJS from CSJS and use a callback to get the result. See Extension Library book pp351 onwards.

2) The quick and dirty option would be to add a button on your page with style "display:none" and add your SSJS in its onclick method. Then use #{id:myButton} in your CSJS to enable you to get the runtime client-side ID of the button and call its onclick method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and sorry for the delayed response. I have tried the dirty option (2nd one) before, a simpler way around, however, can you brief me more about the first option. I have not got hands on the book as of yet..

Comment: As ever, the usual rule of thumb applies that if Tim Tripcony's explained it before, don't try to do it better! I'd advise reading this email trail http://notesin9.com/index.php/2014/05/21/tim-explains-json-rpc-codefortim/. It gives an example and how to pass parameters, which you'll probably need to do. Tim may even have written that chapter of XPages Extension Library book, I can't remember which of us did that chapter.

Comment: Excellent, looks goods, thanks for pointing to the right direction.